# ERROR [08004] [IBM][CLI Driver] SQL30061N - While fetching data from DB2 database tables

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, db2, odbc

I have a tables in DB2 database, and i was able to fetch the data when i develop and test the code in my local solution.

After Deployment in Stage environment i received below error. I am using ASP.NET MVC and C#.

```
ERROR [08004] [IBM][CLI Driver] SQL30061N The database alias or database name "DSNV " was not found at the remote node. SQLSTATE=08004
```

Any idea why i am receiving this error.

Comment: You have an issue with the connection string.  Either the IP address is not accessible on the deploy computer or the credentials (user name, password) are not correct. If you are not using an IP then the ODBC is not set up properly in Control Panel : Admin Toos : ODBC Connections.  See : https://www.connectionstrings.com/ibm-db2/

Comment: Thank You. I am using some wrong hostname and port.